# CSS *:not selector in userscript under Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, userscripts

I'm trying to create a userstyle (installed in **Google Chrome** as a userscript). 
It's just some CSS to hide everything on the page and only show [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xZIO.png).

```
html { height:100%; 
       background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xZIO.png) no-repeat center fixed #FFFFFF !important; 
       overflow:hidden; 
     }
*:not(html) { display:none; }
```

I'd say there's something wrong with my understanding of CSS here, but this *works* in **Mozilla Firefox** (pasted this code in **userContent.css** and it behaves as expected).

Also tried `body` instead of `html`, `visibility:collapse;` instead of `display:none;` and more specific `:not` selectors.

Here is [how **userstyles.org** makes this CSS into a userscript](http://userstyles.org/styles/userjs/53487/Block%20entire%20website%20and%20display%20custom%20graphics.user.js?option-86826=479025&option-86827=479027)

Please explain what's up here! Many thanks!

Comment: So, you say that it works... so what's wrong? Are you trying to say it doesn't work in a certain browser?

Comment: Have you already attempted postfixing `!important`? It's likely that the page's CSS override the userstyle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following code works fine on my chrome. I removed your @namespace line and applied styles on the html element.

```
// @description   Block entire websites in style!
// @author        monn43
// @homepage      http://userstyles.org/styles/53487
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==
(function() {
var css = "";
if (false || (document.domain == "perezhilton.com" ||document.domain.substring(document.domain.indexOf(".perezhilton.com") + 1) == "perezhilton.com") || (document.domain == "fitperez.com" || document.domain.substring(document.domain.indexOf(".fitperez.com") + 1) == "fitperez.com") || (document.domain == "cocoperez.com" || document.domain.substring(document.domain.indexOf(".cocoperez.com") + 1) == "cocoperez.com") || (document.location.href.indexOf("http://perezhilton.com/") == 0))
css += "html { height:100%; background:url(http://i.imgur.com/oqhgG.png) no-repeat center fixed #FFFFFF !important; overflow:hidden; }\n*:not(html) { visibility:hidden; }";
if (typeof GM_addStyle != "undefined") {
GM_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof PRO_addStyle != "undefined") {
PRO_addStyle(css);
} else if (typeof addStyle != "undefined") {
addStyle(css);
} else {
var heads = document.getElementsByTagName("head");
if (heads.length > 0) {
    var node = document.createElement("style");
    node.type = "text/css";
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    heads[0].appendChild(node); 
}
}
})();
```

Comment: Removing the @namespace and `visibility:hidden;` fixed it, thanks!